# Prestashop cloud : How do i resize the image container to best fit the image i have?

Tags: prestashop

[image: Product details page]

Any idea how do i change the size of container so that image gets fit into the container? Also i need to do some customization to 'Add to cart' button.

How do i do all this with prestashop cloud?

Is it possible with cloud or i will have to switch to local code version for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing / looking at `Preferences -> Images` section, there will be all image dimensions including product images. It might help but I am not sure because it depends from the theme you use.

If you want to modify your template files, you can do this by downloading content from FTP. You should have login details (if you don't, contact PS support).

It would be better to do modifications locally and when you are satisfied with the result upload changes to the server. You will need to install store (and downloaded theme) locally because you won't be able to download store files due to restrictions.
Of course if it is only few small changes there might be no point recreating everything on your PC.